# Expression for maximum column index of every row in matrix

Tags: matrices, notation

Let $H$ is $(k \times j)$ matrix. How can one describe "for every maximum column of each row in $H$"?

Can I write $\underset{j}{\text{argmax}} (H_{kj}), {k = 0,\ldots,K}$? I feel something is wrong here.